# Connected $T_2$-space such that the open sets are closed under countable intersection

Tags: gn.general-topology

This question has a trivial starting point: If the open sets of $\mathbb{R}$ were closed under countable intersection, the Euclidean topology would be discrete because for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\{x\} = \bigcap\big\{ (x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}):n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}\big\}$.

**Question.** Is there a connected $T_2$-space $(X,\tau)$ with $X$ uncountable such that for all countable sets ${\cal C} \subseteq \tau$ we have $\bigcap {\cal C}\in\tau$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In other words, you want every $G_\delta$ to be open.  I just learned that such spaces are called [**P-spaces**](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php?title=P-space).

The following paper contains an example of a connected Hausdorff P-space (and yes it is uncountable).

> *Misra, Arvind K.*, [**A topological view of P-spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0016-660X(72)90026-8), General Topology Appl. 2, 349-362 (1972). [ZBL0249.54019](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0249.54019).  [MR317304](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=317304).

The author also mentions that you can't improve much upon "Hausdorff", because every [functionally Hausdorff](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Functionally_Hausdorff_space) P-space is totally disconnected.

Comment: Note that if $X$ is a P-space and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous then $f$ is constant on the connected components of $X$. From this it follows that functionally Hausdorff P-spaces are totally disconnected. Also note that any separable $T_1$ P-space is countable and discrete; in particular it follows that a connected $T_1$ P-space must have uncountable density character.